# How can we lead an equation of $x,y$ by eliminating $\theta,\phi$?

Tags: functions

If we have the following three relations, how can we lead an equation of $x,y$ by eliminating $\theta,\phi$ ?

$$\frac{x\sin\theta}{3}+\frac{y\cos\theta}{4}=\frac{x\sin\phi}{3}+\frac{y\cos\phi}{4}=\frac{\sin\theta\sin\phi}{9}+\frac{\cos\theta\cos\phi}{16}=1$$

In principle, this seems to be possible, but I'm facing difficutly. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Using [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) observe that the roots of the Quadratic Equation $$\frac x3\frac{2t}{1+t^2}+\frac y4\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}=1$$ (in $t$) are $\tan\frac\theta2,\tan\frac\phi2$

Then use Vieta's formula to find $\displaystyle\tan\frac\theta2+\tan\frac\phi2$ and $\displaystyle\tan\frac\theta2\cdot\tan\frac\phi2$

Finally use Weierstrass substitution in the last relation and replace the values of $\displaystyle\tan\frac\theta2+\tan\frac\phi2$ and $\displaystyle\tan\frac\theta2\cdot\tan\frac\phi2$

Comment: Thank you very much! The answer that I got is $17x^2+10y^2=25$.

Comment: @mathlove, my pleasure. Sorry, I did not go till the end. Nice Question, btw. Hope to see some other solutions as well

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can't get $\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)/9 + \cos(\phi)\cos(\theta)/16 = 1$ with real $\phi$ and $\theta$.

According to Maple:

```
with(Groebner):
e1:= x/3*st+y/4*ct; 
e2:= x/3*sp+y/4*cp;
e3:= st*sp/9 + ct*cp/16;
B:= Basis([e1-e2,e2-e3,e3-1,ct^2+st^2-1,cp^2+sp^2-1],
   plex(st,ct,sp,cp,x,y)):
factor(B[1]);
```

$$\left( 10\,{y}^{2}-25+17\,{x}^{2} \right)  \left( 225\,{x}^{4}+240\,{y}^{2}{x}^{2}-210\,{x}^{2}+49+64\,{y}^{4}+112\,{y}^{2} \right) 
$$

An example where $17 x^2 + 10 y^2 \ne 25$ is $x = \sqrt{7/15}$, $y=0$, 
$\cos(\phi) = \cos(\theta) = \sqrt{-128/7}$, $\sin(\phi) = \sin(\theta) = \sqrt{135/7}$.